# Include model associations from within the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I need to clean up my code from using:

```
# class ProjectsController < ApiController
def show
  render json: Project.find_by(id: params[:id]).as_json(include: :user)
end
```

to:

```
render json: Project.find_by(id: params[:id]) // should include the association
```

Is there a way to put this logic in the model? Im using Rails 5 API

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, include: :project // I thought this would work

  def self.foo
    self.includes(:user)
  end
end

# in controller
render json: Project.foo.find_by(id: params[:id]) // nothing
```

What if `Project` belongs to many models and to need to include it by only calling `Project.find(1)`, I will have some nested `includes` in my controller. Could I put all this logic in the model then `Project.find(1)` would show all the associations in json format?

Comment: you can try this, in your Project model: `def as_json(options = {}) super(include: :user) end`

Comment: Hi all... ill try both in a bit then respond.

Comment: @Thanh Apologies for late respond. Sorry. That worked great. Thanks! You could add this as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Project model, override `as_json` method to include association `user`:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(include: :user)
end
```